# MySQL Query to get sum of similar rows

Tags: mysql

This is my student_attendance table:

```
 id_student   |  Id_subject  |  subject_type  |  subject_description  |  total  |  attendance  |date
      124       34               Practicals         PHY-I                  9         9          2014-07
      124       34               Practicals         PHY-I                  9         9          2014-08
      124       34               Theory             PHY-I                  9         9          2014-07
      124       34               Theory             PHY-I                 11        11          2014-08
      124       35               Practicals         CHEM-I                15        15          2014-07
      124       35               Practicals         CHEM-I                 9         9          2014-08
      124       35               Theory             CHEM-I                 7         9          2014-07
      124       35               Theory             CHEM-I                13        14          2014-08
      124       36               Theory             MAT-I                 18        18          2014-07    
      124       36               Theory             MAT-I                 15        15          2014-08
```

This is my subject table:

```
id_subject  |  subject_description
       34             PHY-I
       35             CHEM-I
       36             MAT-I
```

where id_subject is the primary key for this table.

This is my subject_timetable table

```
   id_subject  |  subject_type
      34         Practicals
      34         Theory 
      35         Practicals
      35         Theory 
      36         Theory
```

There is no primary key for student_attendance table and subject_timetable table.

Now i want the sum of attendance and total of the student for two months(i.e july and august 2014) for each subject separately for each subject type(Theory and Practicals).

Please help me to get the suitable query for it.
I had tried with this query but its giving wrong results for some subjects after summing.

My MYSQL Query:

```
SELECT sa.id_student, sa.id_subject, sa.subject_type,
 sub.subject_description, sum(sa.total) as sum,sum(sa.attendance) as attendance
FROM (student_attendance AS sa, subject AS sub, subject_timetable AS st)
WHERE sa.id_division =7 
  AND sa.date BETWEEN  "2014-07-01" AND  "2014-08-01" 
  AND sa.id_student = 124 
  AND sa.id_subject = st.id_subject 
  AND sa.subject_type = st.subject_type 
  AND st.id_subject = sub.id_subject 
group by sa.id_student,sa.subject_type, sa.id_subject
ORDER BY  `sa`.`id_student` ASC
```

And the result what i get is

```
 id_student   |  Id_subject  |  subject_type  |  subject_description  |  total  |  attendance
      124       34       Practicals         PHY-I             18        18       
      124       34       Theory             PHY-I             20        20      
      124       35       Practicals         CHEM-I            39        39                  
      124       35       Theory             CHEM-I            20        23      
      124       36       Theory             MAT-I             48        48
```

As you can see in the result table the value for attendance for CHEM-I(practicals) for july and august is 9 & 15 and the sum of it comes to 24 but in my result table it comes to 39 and same thing is happening for MAT-I subject.

Comment: Because some of your rows are repeated. 15+15+9

Comment: Give the definitions and values for your tables. How can we know what the output should be? And what the rows for each table mean. And where are input rows repeated?

Comment: Hi,philipxy I have provided the necessary tables and values and the query which i tried to get the result.Please help